# Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0". Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, opengl

I'm really confused and lost.

I'm a completely new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS user and I'm trying to run a game on WIne and OpenGL.

I was instructed to use the glxinfo command on my terminal to see if I had opengl and this turned out:

```
glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

I have installed mesa-utils, and I've run some nvidia-current commands or something to install my graphics card.

I'm currently running an Asus A45V, Nvidia GEFORCE 610M, Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I appreciate any reply, I'm really frustrated after about an hour's worth of looking online for solutions.